# Multiple producers, single consumer: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock

Tags: go

I have been following a pattern of checking if there is anything in the channel before proceeding with work:

```
func consume(msg <-chan message) {
  for {
    if m, ok := <-msg; ok {
      fmt.Println("More messages:", m)
    } else {
      break
    }
  }
}
```

that is based on this [video](https://youtu.be/YS4e4q9oBaU?t=23240). Here is my full code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

type message struct {
    body string
    code int
}

var markets []string = []string{"BTC", "ETH", "LTC"}

// produces messages into the chan
func produce(n int, market string, msg chan<- message, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    // for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    var msgToSend = message{
        body: strings.Join([]string{"market: ", market, ", #", strconv.Itoa(1)}, ""),
        code: 1,
    }
    fmt.Println("Producing:", msgToSend)
    msg <- msgToSend
    // }
    wg.Done()
}

func receive(msg <-chan message, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for {
        if m, ok := <-msg; ok {
            fmt.Println("Received:", m)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Breaking from receiving")
            break
        }
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    msgC := make(chan message, 100)
    defer func() {
        close(msgC)
    }()
    for ix, market := range markets {
        wg.Add(1)
        go produce(ix+1, market, msgC, &wg)
    }
    wg.Add(1)
    go receive(msgC, &wg)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

If you try to run it, we get the deadlock at the very end before we ever print a message that we are about to break. Which, tbh, makes sense, since the last time, when there is nothing else in the chan, we are trying to pull the value out, and so we get this error. But then this pattern isn't workable `if m, ok := <- msg; ok`. How do I make this code work & why do I get this deadlock error (presumably this pattern should work?).

Comment: yes, he mentions selects later, but I was wondering what is off in this case

Comment: *"Which, tbh, makes sense, since the last time, when there is nothing else in the chan, we are trying to pull the value out, and so we get this error."* This sentence suggests that you understand exactly why you're getting the error... what do you mean by "what is off"?

Comment: that was a guess. Because according to the video that I linked, this is the pattern one would use to identify when there is nothing else in the channel to break out of the for loop. But this does not happen.

Comment: I think I know the cause! the wg.Done in receive never gets the chance to be called! we break before it, and so then wg.Wait does not know what to do! or not...

Comment: Breaking is not returning, if the break would be hit then so would be wg.Done, the problem is break is never hit because the if conditional is stuck waiting for the receive. No?

Comment: correct about the break! and what you say makes sense. But I have seen this ok pattern elsewhere too: https://medium.com/rungo/anatomy-of-channels-in-go-concurrency-in-go-1ec336086adb in the for loop section.

Comment: *"The value of ok is true if the value received was delivered by a successful send operation to the channel, or **false if it is a zero value generated because the channel is closed and empty**."* (https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator) `if m, ok := <-msg; ok {` will stop blocking once you close the channel, however your close deferred and so is blocked by the bottom wg.Wait

Comment: good spot! How do I close it in this case without deferring? other goroutines might still be sending

Comment: one option might be sending an additional param to the produce function that is a flag, that if set to true triggers the close call inside of the producer. Do not know how conventional this is and whether this is golang best practices.

Comment: To be honest I'm not 100% sure this is correct, and if it is i'm not sure whether it is the preferred approach, but here goes: https://play.golang.com/p/dKnJP7Y9tuq

Comment: It works :) Nice idea about two wait groups! Feel free to post the answer. Thanks for your help! I will have a look at using selects in this context now.

Comment: If you want you can go ahead and accept any of the provided answers, I'm a bit too lazy to write out mine ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you do have multiple writers on a single channel, you have a bit of a challenge, because the easy way to do this in Go in general is to have a single writer on a single channel, and then have that single writer close the channel upon sending the last datum:

```
func produce(... args including channel) {
    defer close(ch)
    for stuff_to_produce {
        ch <- item
    }
}
```

This pattern has the nice property that no matter how you get out of `produce`, the channel gets closed, signalling the end of production.

You're not using this pattern—you deliver one channel to many goroutines, each of which can send *one* message—so you need to move the `close` (or, of course, use yet some other pattern).  The simplest way to express the pattern you need is this:

```
func overall_produce(... args including channel ...) {
    var pg sync.WaitGroup
    defer close(ch)
    for stuff_to_produce {
        pg.Add(1)
        go produceInParallel(ch, &pg) // add more args if appropriate
    }
    pg.Wait()
}
```

The `pg` counter accumulates active producers.  Each must call `pg.Done()` to indicate that it is done using `ch`.  The overall producer now waits for them all to be done, then *it* closes the channel on its way out.

(If you write the inner `produceInParallel` function as a closure, you don't need to pass `ch` and `pg` to it explicitly.  You may also write `overallProducer` as a closure.)

Note that your single consumer's loop is probably best expressed using the `for ... range` construct:

```
func receive(msg <-chan message, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for m := range msg {
        fmt.Println("Received:", m)
    }
    wg.Done()
}
```

(You mention an intent to add a `select` to the loop so that you can do some other computing if a message is not yet ready.  If that code cannot be spun off into independent goroutines, you will in fact need the fancier `m, ok := <-msg` construct.)

Note also that the `wg` for `receive`—which may turn out to be unnecessary, depending on how you structure other things—is quite independent from the wait-group `pg` for the producers.  While it's true that, as written, the consumer cannot be done until all the producers are done, we'd like to wait independently for the producers to be done, so that we can close the channel in the overall-producer wrapper.

Comment: I love this. This is exactly what I was looking for, explanation for why it doesn't work, so that I avoid it. Thank you very much torek. I will have a read through this properly today and will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I have made few fixes that made it work:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

type message struct {
    body string
    code int
}

var markets []string = []string{"BTC", "ETH", "LTC"}

// produces messages into the chan
func produce(n int, market string, msg chan<- message, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    // for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    var msgToSend = message{
        body: strings.Join([]string{"market: ", market, ", #", strconv.Itoa(1)}, ""),
        code: 1,
    }
    fmt.Println("Producing:", msgToSend)
    msg <- msgToSend
    // }

}

func receive(msg <-chan message, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for {
        if m, ok := <-msg; ok {
            fmt.Println("Received:", m)
            wg.Done()
        }
    }
}

func consume(msg <-chan message) {
  for {
    if m, ok := <-msg; ok {
      fmt.Println("More messages:", m)
    } else {
      break
    }
  }
}

func main() {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    msgC := make(chan message, 100)
    defer func() {
        close(msgC)
    }()
    for ix, market := range markets {
        wg.Add(1)
        go produce(ix+1, market, msgC, &wg)
    }

    go receive(msgC, &wg)
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Breaking from receiving")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only when `main` returns, you can `close(msgC)`, but meanwhile `receive` is waiting for `close` signal, that's why DeadLock occurs. After producing messages, close the channel.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

type message struct {
    body string
    code int
}

var markets []string = []string{"BTC", "ETH", "LTC"}

// produces messages into the chan
func produce(n int, market string, msg chan<- message, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    // for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    var msgToSend = message{
        body: strings.Join([]string{"market: ", market, ", #", strconv.Itoa(1)}, ""),
        code: 1,
    }
    fmt.Println("Producing:", msgToSend)
    msg <- msgToSend
    // }
    wg.Done()
}

func receive(msg <-chan message, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for {
        if m, ok := <-msg; ok {
            fmt.Println("Received:", m)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Breaking from receiving")
            break
        }
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    msgC := make(chan message, 100)
    // defer func() {
    //  close(msgC)
    // }()
    for ix, market := range markets {
        wg.Add(1)
        go produce(ix+1, market, msgC, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait() // wait for producer
    close(msgC)
    wg.Add(1)
    go receive(msgC, &wg)
    wg.Wait()
}
```