# How to close a channel with multiple senders?

Tags: go, channel

I have a case where I need to fan out receivers that send to the same channel:

```
func MessagesFromSQS(ctx context.Context, sqsClient sqsiface.SQSAPI) chan *sqs.Message {
    messages := make(chan *sqs.Message)

    go func() {
        defer close(messages)
        wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

        for i := 0; i < parallelSQSReaders; i++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func() {
                defer wg.Done()

                for {
                    select {
                    case <-ctx.Done():
                        return

                    default:
                        // ...

                        for _, message := range result.Messages {
                            messages <- message
                        }
                    }
                }
            }()
        }

        wg.Wait()
    }()

    return messages
}
```

To me this makes sense. However, the race detector complains that different goroutines and sending and closing the channel. I realize that the goroutine thats responsible for sending should be the same one that closes, but what's the correct way to do this?

EDIT/SOLVED: Thanks for your responses. It turns out I wasn't reading the race detector stack trace correctly. I assumed that the code I changed introduced the bug, instead of uncovering a bug in the SQS mock. Once I correctly synchronized `ReceiveMessage()` it was fine.

Comment: Is there other code that sends to `messages`?  Is the code reported by the race detector all in the anonymous function defined in `MessagesFromSQS`?

Comment: Perhaps not quite the same situation, but see my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/58793428/1256452. The code you've shown here seems fine.

Answer (score 3):

Close the channel when you know there won't be any more writes i.e. when all worker go-routines are complete.

So:

```
wg.Wait()
close(messages)
```

P.S. I'd restructure your polling of context cancelation by combining it in a select with your channel writes e.g.

```
for _, message := range result.Messages {

    select {
        case messages <- message:
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
    }

}
```

Comment: That is a less safe way or what I've already got. The problem is the `close()` happens in a different goroutine as the send.

Comment: It's not uncommon to close a channel from other go-routine(s) writers. The waitgroup combined with the wait() ensures no one is left to write to the channel. This is perfectly safe coordination.

Comment: Also, one should never get a data-race on a channel - they are designed for concurrent use. (There are caveats to this - but as long as the channel is initialized before use - you should be safe). I suspect (and as @CeriseLimon commented) the data race is with `result.Messages`. If this is a slice and it's being written to as workers are reading from it - then that's a major issue. You may want to think about using an input channel instead - and worker read from that. Then any data-race should disappear.

Comment: Thanks for that. It turns out I wasn't reading the race detector stack trace correctly. I assumed that the code I changed introduced the bug, instead of uncovering a bug in the SQS mock. Once I correctly synchronized the method that returns the messages it was fine.